# Swift, Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var currencySegment: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var sourceMoneyField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var targetMoneyLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func convertMoney(_ sender: Any) {
    let ratio : Double
    switch currencySegment.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        ratio = 0.00085
    case 1:
        ratio = 1178.5
    default :
        ratio = 1.0
    }
    let targetMoneyString: String
    if let sourceMoney = Double(sourceMoneyField.text!){
        targetMoneyString = "\(sourceMoney * ratio)"
    }else {
        targetMoneyString = "Error"
    }

    targetMoneyLabel.text = targetMoneyString
}
}
```

In the last part, I get error which is:

> thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0) error

To the `targetMoneyLabel.text = targetMoneyString` part.

I think I have to change last sentence, I try to read and watch many videos to fix it, but I can't.

Is the problem related to `nil`? I am new to Swift.

Comment: have you rechecked your outlets are properly connected?

Comment: in my playground your code is work properly ,i am not getting error

Comment: if targetMoneyLabel != nil {
        targetMoneyLabel.text = targetMoneyString
    }

use this code instead of last line, if app doesn't crash, then you must reconnect outlets again

Comment: In your error, you removed any useful information.

Comment: Thank you so much, i used " 
if targetMoneyLabel != nil { targetMoneyLabel.text = targetMoneyString } ", i finally removed my error

Comment: but in the app, it did not work well, maybe i have to fix some functions! anyway Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be about unwrapping the variable.

You can try this:

```
guard let targetMoneyString.characters.count > 0 else  {
    return
}
targetMoneyLabel.text = targetMoneyString
```

Comment: i did, but it made another problem which is "variable binding in a condition requires an initializer".

Comment: Good news is that anyway i fixed past error. Thank you! your suggestion was so good^^, i will keep trying it